# Problema con carga de CSS en bootsfaces offline

Tags: java, datatables, jsf, font-awesome

Tengo un problema con un proyecto java web JSF usando bootsfaces estando desconectado de internet. La biblioteca por defecto carga dos ficheros desde internet:

- **datatable.css**
- **font-awesome.css**

El proyecto al existir la posibilidad de estar offline da problemas a la hora de cargar la página por no encontrar estos ficheros, ya lo descargue y puse las dependencias en las páginas que los requiere, pero aun al cargar la página y estar offline se demora en cargar la página porque sigue buscando esos ficheros. Bootsfaces es un jar asi que es poco probable que pueda buscar la llamada a esos ficheros.
Existe alguna forma de eliminar la carga de ficheros en tiempo de ejecución?
Hasta más me conviene cargar los ficheros locales debido a que en momentos de lenta conectividad puede ralentizar la carga del sitio.

Este es un fragmento de código de la plantilla padre:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{templateBean.request}/assets/admin/img/favicon.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{templateBean.request}/assets/admin/css/datatable/datatables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{templateBean.request}/assets/admin/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{templateBean.request}/assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

...
```

[image: Log de errores que da la consola del navegador al no encontrar los ficheros en internet]

[image: Listado de ficheros que debe cargar la página la abrirse, en rojo los ficheros con error]

Comment: Deberías poner tu código aquí (lo relevante) para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a [Stephan Ruah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3466464/stephan-rauh) de Stack Overflow en inglés por la contribución. La solución ya fue probada y funciona correctamente. Consiste en modificar el fichero web.xml y añadir las siguientes líneas. Estas líneas evitan que bootsfaces descargue los elementos de internet y utiliza sólo los locales. Por supuesto, es necesario descargar los ficheros y añadirlos al proyecto utilizando los estándares html o los de JSF.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>net.bootsfaces.get_datatable_from_cdn</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```